# refresh tabs fragment and viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I setup my viewpager according to the data I get from my database. If there are 3 person, I setup 3 tabs.
Now through settings, I can add a delete a person. I want to reload the tabs according to the updated data. I know onResume is called again when my fragment is accessed. I'm doing this but this is not refreshing the tabs, they should have one less or one more tab depending on the update in database.

```
 @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("Refresh", " "+ MainActivity.allowRefresh);
        if (MainActivity.allowRefresh)
        {

            MainActivity.allowRefresh = false;

            setupViewPager(viewPager);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to re attached the viewpager with tablayout. Change the dataset that you use in your `viewpager.setAdapter(adapter)` and call `adapter.onDataSetChanged()`